# MySQL inserting&withdrawing images from MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, bitmap

First i want to be able to take images with my phone, using something like bitmap and then having that photo uploaded to MySQL. Lateron i'm going to want to withdraw that image aka put somewhere else on the app.

This is what i have (it won't work because i need to have the image on a file location and not a bitmap.):

```
public static void InsertImage(String user_id, String gender, Blob image, String filePath) {
    connection(); //this is where i got my connection information this works fine btw.

    filePath = "i don't want to have anything here";
    try {
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        PreparedStatement statement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO picture (user_id, gender, image) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
        statement.setString(2, user_id);
        statement.setString(3, gender);         
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

        statement.setBlob(8, image);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        statement.close();
        connect.close();
        //3 means column
        System.out.println("Worked");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also how would i go about withdrawing it? Also if using bitmap won't work since it's Blob i use in mySQL, what else could i use? link to any tutorials would be great preferably videos.. i hate reading :s

Comment: General advice: Don't store images in the DB. It'll just lead to pain and suffering later on. Store the images in the filesystem, and store METADATA about the image in the db.

Comment: filesystem? care to aloborate? never heard of that term, nor metadata.. these images are suppose to be a part of the app, aka you need to use internet to see them etc, now would that work with some kind of filesystem? because that sounds local.